# Date conversion from date and time string to dd/mm/yyyy using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi guys I am using the Google RSS API (ATOM) to extract RSS feeds. It returns a published date  in JSON format in a long string version like:

```
Sun, 24 Jun 2012 17:00:00 -0700
```

How can I convert this string to show `24/06/2012` using JavaScript for example?

Comment: Do you need the leading zeros (e.g. `01/01/2001`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
var d = new Date('Sun, 24 Jun 2012 17:00:00 -0700');
var day = d.getDay();
var month = d.getMonth();
var date = d.getDate();  
var year = d.getFullYear();
var formatted = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Comment: I don't agree with your answer since the `getDay()` returns the day (monday, sunday,etc) and not the month's day (1->31).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Date.parse function

```
var d     = Date.parse('Sun, 24 Jun 2012 17:00:00 -0700');
var day   = new Date(d);
var month = d.getMonth();
var year  = d.getFullYear();
var formatted_date = day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this library the other day, its really good for manipulating dates in Javascript, behaves a bit like Python's Datetime object. http://momentjs.com
It can instantiate from a string, I think the format you would need is something like this:

```
var day = moment("Sun, 24 Jun 2012 17:00:00 -0700", "ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");
console.log( day.format('dd/MM/YY') );
```

It does say however that creating dates from strings isn't particularly quick, I guess the benefit of this is more for manipulating date/times rather than simply reformatting them.